# What font does the Japanese locale for Windows 7 use?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, fonts, locale, japanese

The command line font changes when you change locale from English to Japanese. What is the name of the font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**

The font is called Terminal (both for English and ), and the font file name of the Japanese one is `vga932.fon` (located, naturally, in `C:\Windows\Fonts`)

**Long Answer**

The Windows 7 (in Windows 10 that changed) Command Prompt uses an old bitmap type font called Terminal/Raster:

[image]

That font is one of the `.fon` files in the `C:\Windows\Fonts folder`, all of these font files are named something like `vga***.fon`, where the start stands for a number, this number is one of the Windows codepages, and whatever codepage the System Locale language is using that is the font the CMD will use.

So since [`932`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_932) is the Japanese codepage that Windows uses, the font CMD uses is `vga932.fon`

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I copied the vga932.fon (from command line, couldn't see it in folder) and renamed it with FontForge to install and use it without having to change to Japanese locale.